# Can views relate two vocabularies?

Tags: views

I want to use `Views` to show a `vocabulary` that has field added to another vocabulary, is that possible?

Comment: Pretty much everything is possible ;) Views support relationships quite well. How have you tried to do it so far?

Comment: I had to use them as parent/child terms, but if view can do it that would be great but how?